# C# Client Send more than one message to server

Tags: c#, client, tcpclient, streamreader, streamwriter

I am having trouble when trying to send more than one message back to the server.
An example would be:

Client sends to server

Server responds

Client then changes the response and sends it back

And then reads the response of the server again.

What I have so far:

```
 Stream stream = client.GetStream();

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

 else if (args.Length == 2)
        {
            while (args[1] != response)
            {
                //  response = sr.ReadLine();
                if (args[1] != response)
                {

                    // this is what should be put in sw.write for the updated database entry
                    // <name><space><location><CR><LF>
                    // cssbct +  " " + "is in fenner", so "cssbct location has changed"
                    // args[0] + " " + response


                    // response is now what the arg is
                    response = args[1];
                    // write the new response so that it will be sent to the server
                    sw.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + response);
                    // send it to the server
                      sw.Flush();


                    // write out the args and that the location has changed
                    //  Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + " location changed to be" + " " + response);

                    // Just testing what the response should be 
                    Console.WriteLine(args[0] + " " + response);


                    string Response2 = "";
                    // read the response from the server
                    Response2 = sr.ReadLine();



                    // if it equals "OK" do this
                    if (Response2 == "OK")
                    {
                        // drops connection to the server
                        // probably not what is needed but look at later date
                        Console.WriteLine(response);

                        Console.WriteLine("Client connection closed");
                        client.Close();
                    }

                    if (sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("End of stream has been reached");
                    }
```

I am getting an error on the sw.flush(),   The error says that  "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software".

Any help is appreciated.

If the flush is commented out the end of stream is reached.

Error Message Being received after the flush() when trying to do the read.

https://ibb.co/hgNKrF

Comment: Can you please explain what is sw? It might be a StreamWriter. But how you created it becomes important if you want an answer.

Comment: @Vijay Sorry forgot to add that, yes it is streamWriter/reader

Comment: Clients stream cannot be used after it has been closed. Which you are doing here if response2  is ok.

Comment: Done commented out for now, my main problem is that with the flush then trying to read the response after that it crashes. with this error : https://ibb.co/hgNKrF, The line Response2 = sr.ReadLine();

Comment: What @Fildor said. And I'm guessing the `while` loops again with the connection now closed.